# How to keep google-cloud-auth.json securely in app.yaml as an environmental variable?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm new to deployment/securing keys, and I'm not sure how to securely store the google-cloud-auth.json (auth required for creating the API client) outside of source code to prevent leaking credentials.

I've currently secured my API keys and tokens in my app.yaml file specifying them as environmental variables which successfully work as expected and shown below.

```
accessruntime: nodejs10
env_variables:
  SECRET_TOKEN: "example"
  SECRET_TOKEN2: "example2"
```

However my google-cloud-auth.json is kept as its own file since the parameter used for creating the client requires a path string.

```
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
...
const file = "./google-cloud-auth.json"; 

// Creates a BigQuery client
const bigquery = new BigQuery({
                projectId: projectId,
                datasetId: datasetId,
                tableId: tableId,
                keyFilename: file
});
```

Comment: Why do you use a service account? Do you have a special need for using it? Is it special?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Setting Up Authentication for Server to Server Production Applications](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production):

1. GCP client libraries will make use of the ADC (Application Default Credentials) to find the credentials meant to be used by the app.
2. What ADC does is basically to check if the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` **env** variable is set with the path to a service account file.
3. In case the **env** variable is not set, ADC will use the default service account provided by App Engine.

With this information I can suggest a couple of solutions to provide these credentials safely:

- If you require to use a specific service account, set the path to the file with the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. [This section](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#setting_the_environment_variable) explains how to do that.
- If you are not a fan of moving credential files around, I would suggest trying to use the default service account provided by the App Engine.

I just created a new project and deployed a basic app by mixing these 2 guides:

- [BigQuery Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries)
- [Quickstart for Node.js in the App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/quickstart)

My **app.yaml** had nothing more than the `runtime: nodejs10` line, and I was still able to query through the BigQuery client library, using the default service account.

This account comes with the Project/Editor role and you can add any additional roles you need.